Bing maps Geofencing
I am trying to use bingmaps V8 polygon, then use the shape of the polygon to extract coordinates from it as geofences and try to print them in the console
This is my code
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const BingMap: React.FC = () => {
const [drawingManager, setDrawingManager] = useState<any>(null); // State to hold the drawing manager instance
  const [geofenceCoordinates, setGeofenceCoordinates] = useState<any[]>([]); // State to store geofence coordinates

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadBingMapScript = async () => {
      try {
        const bingKey = "**************"; 

        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = `https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=${bingKey}`;
        script.async = true;
        script.defer = true;

        script.onload = () => {
          window.GetMap = () => {
            const mapElement = document.getElementById("myMap");
            if (mapElement) {
              const map = new window.Microsoft.Maps.Map(mapElement, {
                credentials: bingKey,
              });

              window.Microsoft.Maps.loadModule(
                "Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools",
                () => {
                  const tools = new window.Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools(map);
                  setDrawingManager(tools);

                  tools.showDrawingManager((manager: any) => {
                    setDrawingManager(manager); // Storing drawing manager instance in state
                  });

                  // Attaching event handler for drawing end
                  window.Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(
                    tools,
                    "drawingEnded",
                    handleDrawingEnded
                  );
                }
              );
            } else {
              console.error("Error: Element with ID 'myMap' not found.");
            }
          };
        };

        script.onerror = (error) => {
          console.error("Error loading Bing Maps script:", error);
        };

        document.body.appendChild(script);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error loading Bing Maps script:", error);
      }
    };

    loadBingMapScript();

    return () => {
      
    };
  }, []);

  const handleDrawingEnded = (event: any) => {
    const shapes = event.shapes;
    const coordinates = shapes
      .map((shape: any) => {
        if (
          shape.getType() ===
            window.Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools.ShapeType.polyline ||
          shape.getType() ===
            window.Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools.ShapeType.polygon
        ) {
          const vertices = shape.getLocations();
          const bounds =
            window.Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(vertices);

          return {
            northLatitude: bounds.getNorth().toFixed(4),
            southLatitude: bounds.getSouth().toFixed(4),
            eastLongitude: bounds.getEast().toFixed(4),
            westLongitude: bounds.getWest().toFixed(4),
          };
        }
        return null;
      })
      .filter((coords: any) => coords !== null);

    setGeofenceCoordinates(coordinates);
    console.log("Geofence coordinates:", coordinates);
  };

  const setDrawingMode = (mode: string) => {
    if (drawingManager) {
      drawingManager.setDrawingMode(
        window.Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools.DrawingMode[mode]
      );
    }
  };

  const handleSubmitGeofence = () => {
    console.log("Submitting geofence with coordinates:", geofenceCoordinates);
    // Here you can perform additional logic to send the geofence coordinates to a backend or perform other actions
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id="myMap"
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "600px", backgroundColor: "gray" }}
      ></div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setDrawingMode("polyline")}>
          Draw Polyline
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => setDrawingMode("polygon")}>Draw Polygon</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleSubmitGeofence}>Submit Geofence</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BingMap;


and I was expecting an array with ccordinates printed in the console but this is what is returned in the console"Submitting geofence with coordinates: Array(0)"
Explanation;
I created a new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon object to hold the user-drawn shape. Then added event listeners for the 'mousedown' and 'mouseup' events on the map.
When the user starts drawing the shape (on 'mousedown'), I add the location of the mouse click to the polygon's vertices and redraw the polygon on the map.
When the user finishes drawing the shape (on 'mouseup'), I get the coordinates of the polygon's vertices, calculate the bounding box of the polygon using Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(), and then extract the coordinates of the bounding box.
Finally, I log the coordinates of the bounding box to the console, which represent the exact coordinates of the shape's borders.


Have you checked the console for errors, you likely will see one. In your handleDrawingEnded callback you have a variable called event and then try to access event.shapes. This is not what the callback receives. The callback only receives the shape that has finished being drawing.
Additionally, the shapes in Bing Maps don't have a getType function, nor is there a Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools.ShapeType namespace. Instead, use instanceof. For example: shape instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Polygon.
Here is what your handleDrawingEnded function should look like:
const handleDrawingEnded = (shape: any) => {
    if (shape instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Polyline || shape instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Polygon) 
    {
        const vertices = shape.getLocations();
        const bounds = window.Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(vertices);

        var coordinates =  {
            northLatitude: bounds.getNorth().toFixed(4),
            southLatitude: bounds.getSouth().toFixed(4),
            eastLongitude: bounds.getEast().toFixed(4),
            westLongitude: bounds.getWest().toFixed(4),
        };

        setGeofenceCoordinates(coordinates);
        console.log("Geofence coordinates:", coordinates);
    }
};

That said, the approach you were taking with event.shapes looks similar to how Azure Maps events work.
Note, unless you have a hard requirement for using Bing Maps (already have a license, have been told you have to use it, or are adding on to an existing app) you should avoid developing new things with Bing Maps. Its retirement was announced and it is better to develop with what Microsoft will be supporting longer term, Azure Maps.

Thank you so much for the correction. It now works fine
